# How do I add custom data and fields to the Contacts screen in Android?

Tags: java, android, android-contacts

I'm trying to add a custom data field and MIME type to the Contacts screen. Is there a way to do this such that when a user views a contact with my data saved on it, my field appears there? This is something I've seen other apps do--how do the Facebook, Twitter, Last.fm, etc. apps add their status information to contacts, for example? I can't seem to figure it out from the Contacts API documentation.